# how to create a complete list of diads form a vertex list

Tags: r, igraph

how can I create a complete list of dyads from a vertex list?
I have a list (1, 2, 3...) and I need to generate a list containing all possible dyads from that list (1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2,...).
I've tried with get.edgelist, but it doesn't work, because the graph is not fully connected (all nodes are connected among them).

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `expand.grid(list(v1), 2)`

Comment: @akrun,  Do you mean `expand.grid(list(v1), list(v1))` ?

Comment: I forgot the `rep` `expand.grid(rep(list(v1), 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Using igraph, you can grab all edges of a graph using `E(g)`. If you'd want all possible edges, you can apply it on a complete graph (a graph that is fully connected). If the vertices in your graph are indeed in sequence from 1 to `n`, you can use `make_full_graph()` to make a *K<sub>n</sub>* - that is to say a fully connected graph. In this example, the graph has 14 vertices.

```
g <- make_full_graph(14, directed=F)
el <- as_edgelist(g)
edges <- E(g)
edges_list <- split(el, rep(1:nrow(el), each = ncol(el)))
edges_vert <- unlist(list(t(el)))
```

`edges` will be the igraph-object, but I think what you're after is a list in R, like `edges_list`.

As you see, `length(edges_list)` is *91* since it is an undirected graph, and the number of edges in complete graphs is a function of the number of vertices.
A complete graph with *n* vertices is commonly written *K<sub>n</sub>* and has these many edges:

[image: n]

Note that in igraph *dyads* are called *edges* and *nodes* are called *vertices*.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a complete graph from an existing one, not completely connected.